# New to SP, very confused about workflows - how can I accomplish a wizard / multi-step like "form"?

Tags: workflow

Very new to SP, and I've been reading up on workflows but cannot get my head around how to accomplish a wizard/multi-step type "form".

I have set up subsites for individual client's wherein I have all the pertinent lists / libraries set up. Some lists the admin controls, other lists/libraries the client can contribute to. One major component of the subsite I am trying to create is data collection for a legal service. Now, I realized I cannot use lists to collect repeating information (let's say a user has 3 properties for which I am collecting the same type of info (columns, etc.)), and I don't want to get involved yet with InfoPath because of the learning curve.

But I got to thinking I could just parse something like that out into a list that can collect repeating information - I consider it one subset of my entire data collection.

I can also use a contact list to collect their information, and possibly info on their relatives (again, this could be considered "repeating") - this is a separate list.

I thought to utilize workflows to "combine" these lists into what seemed like a wizard / multi-step form for the client.  Would it be possible to do something like this? I thought I could start "Step 1" and then when the client is finished some mechanism in the workflow determines "finished" on this step, and then starts another workflow?

The big problem I am having is in understanding whether or not I can do something like this with multiple lists.

Any ideas/examples/suggestions?  Much appreciated.

I am using Sharepoint Online through Office365, on an E3 Plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you mentioned you don't want to dive into InfoPath yet, but I think that is probably your best solution.  The learning curve on that would be simpler that doing custom code or rigging together a hodgepodge solution that isn't reliable.

Alternatively, you could use an Access Web Database (basically you create a "web" Access database with forms and such that gets published to SharePoint).

Comment: Couldn't find any reliable resources to create an InfoPath multi-step wizard. Plus, I was hoping to have a web part that said "Start Form", and then it switched to "Step 1 (Complete), Step 2 (Incomplete) ..." or some such thing so that users can come back. It's a long form I am contemplating for the client to complete, and might require several visits rather than one long session.

Comment: Neglected to mention I am on Office365 with an E3 plan. Sorry about that. Updating question with that info.

Comment: In InfoPath, this can be done with Views.  Your first view is your first step and you change to the next view as your move along.  You would also create a rule that runs when opened to set the current view to the appropriate step based on data in the form.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that. My searches aren't coming up with anything about that (creating rules when opened, etc.). Can you lend a resource link. :)

Comment: Here is a place to get you started: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/CH010059827.aspx.  You will want to also explore Rules as you will rely on them a bit too.

Comment: And InfoPath is available on your O365 E3 plan.